# Django email not sending mail

Tags: django, django-email

I created a view for email that worked for sometime but recently stopped sending mails. However I can see the mail in the console. I don't know what is wrong.

I have used both send_email and Emailmessage but none of them work.

views.py

```
def mail(request):
    msg = EmailMessage('Request Callback',
                   'Here is the message.', to=['****@gmail.com'])
    msg.send()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

settings.py

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '****@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = '****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '***********'
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you've got more information to add, please edit the original question.

Comment: I am new so I don't know much. thanks.